# How to create Angular 8 hosted PDF file download without opening browser

Tags: angular, pdf, download

I need to create a hosted PDF file download when clicking the button without opening the browser how to do that it in Angular

Answer (score 1):

If the PDF file is hosted at client side itself, just use HTML `download` attribute on anchor element like below

`<a href="/path/to/the/hosted/pdf/file.pdf" download>`

Reference : [download attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_a_download.asp)

Comment: Not in client-side, it has hosted in server-side

Comment: Even it from the server-side, the above code works. What is the file link address you are getting and assigning to href attribute of anchor? and also your website address?

Comment: If the file is being opened in new tab, then download attribute works like instead of navigating to new page, just downloads it

Comment: <a href="https://pats.cs.cf.ac.uk/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=project-report.pdf" download>Download</a> yes, I tried this code but when I clicking the download button pdf file opening in a new tab..I need add when the user clicks button save that PDF file..

Comment: I think, that is because of cross origin sites issue. You can refer here for alternate solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/52466102/8593983